# enter vars to function with interval

Tags: function, undefined, intervals, var

i have these two functions:

1.the first one

```
      someFunction = function(objectname){
      var vidobject = objectname;
      setInterval( function() { interfunc(vidobject); }, 500 );
```

};

which gets an object from a button click.

2.And the second one which i want to use with the inverval:

interfunc(obje){

alert(obje)

});

but when the alert comes up it writes "undefined" and if il use for example vidobject.id it wont event alert and if i alert the object in the first function it alerts succefully
any solutions? :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you calling setInterval inside setInterval?

Just alert in first setInterval's callback as you said.

**UPDATE**

It seems the object is cleared somewhere when your interval callback is called.

Try to have clone object before setInterval.

To copy an object check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object).

Or if you just need some value from object, just keep the value from the object.

```
someFunction = function(objectname){
  var vidobjectID = objectname.id;
  setInterval( function() { interfunc(vidobjectID); }, 500 );
};
```

Comment: its my function name,changed it,stil the same problem appears :